# npx create-react-app fails while executing yarnpkg on big sur

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx, macos-big-sur

I've found a few posts on this already but none of the existing solutions seem to work.

- OSX Big Sur
- yarn 1.22.10
- npm 7.0.11
- I updated xcode developer tools.
- I deleted npm cache
- I removed .npm and .yarnrc folders

And then trying to start a new React app with `npx create-react-app` and getting the following:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "expected workspace package to exist for \"eslint\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/gdboling/Projects/BalancedComp/clients/packages/rewards/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/gdboling/Projects/BalancedComp/clients/packages/rewards has failed.
```

The log file has:

```
26 verbose stack Error: command failed
26 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
26 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:329:20)
26 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1055:16)
26 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:5)
```

Comment: Please do get back and self-answer if you've solved this @Gregg

Comment: Is there any workout?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem on macOS Big Sur. I generally use `brew` to install my packages. Simply upgrading the packages solved it for me:

```
brew upgrade
```

and afterwards

```
brew cleanup
```

You may need to restart `npm` after `brew` finished upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue with a Vue project. I am using OSX Catalina and npm 7.0.8.

My error was resolved with a post found here: https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/6258/errors-updating-to-v2/5

With the answer of *FrankM*:

---

Check your index.template.html.
Replace **htmlWebpackPlugin.options.ctx.mod**e with **ctx.mode**

---

Maybe this helps and you have a similar entry anywhere in your project.